# Suitescript 2.0 setLineItemValues equivalent

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

In `suitescript 1.0` we could use `sublist.setLineItemValues(searchArray)` to set sublist fields from search results.  How do we do this in `Suitescript 2.0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I do not see an equivalent for this anywhere in the documentation for `N/ui/serverWidget.Sublist`. This is definitely be a significant deficiency that I hope gets added soon.

Answer (score 1):

work with `sublist.setSublistValue(options)` in suitescript 2.0 it is equivalent to `sublist.setLineItemValues(searchArray)`.

`sublist.setSublistValue(options)` 
With this method you need to set the column values individually.(use loop).